# foreach() reporting invalid argument when argument is definitely an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, indices

I know many extremely similar `foreach` problems have been posted before, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this. I'm sure it's on here somewhere in the soup of identically-titled questions.

I'm using [this ESRI shapefile reader class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1741-PHP-Read-vectorial-data-from-geographic-shape-files.html) in a script, and I have this function:

```
function csv_generate($shapefile){
    $startTime=microtime(1);
    $imported=new ShapeFile($shapefile,array('noparts'=>false));
    $names=explode('/',$shapefile);
    $output=fopen('output/'.$names[count($names)-1].'.csv','w');
    while($object=$imported->getNext()){
        $data=$object->getDbfData();
        file_put_contents('output/'.$names[count($names)-1].'.txt',implode("\t",array_keys($data)));
        $shape=$object->getShpData();
        $shapes=array();
/*LINE 246*/    foreach($shape['parts'] as $poly){
            $points=array();
            foreach($poly['points'] as $point){
                $temp=round_away($point['x']).','.round_away($point['y']);
                if(isset($points[count($points)-1])&&$points[count($points)-1]!==$temp)$points[]=$temp;
            }
            $shapes[]=implode(';',$points);
        }
/*LINE 254*/    fputs($output,implode("\t",$data)."\t".$shape['numparts']."\t".implode("\t",$shapes)."\r\n"); 
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

Running this code yields:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: "parts" in [...] on line 246
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...] on line 246
Notice: Undefined offset: "numparts" in [...] on line 254
```

OK, so I must have gotten the keys wrong, then. Easy fix, right? NO. Of course not.

The result of `var_dump`ing `$shape` is:

`array(7) { [...] ["numparts"]=> int(1) [...] ["parts"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["points"]=> array(175) { [0]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> [...]`

I've tried rewriting the `foreach` loops to things such as:

```
foreach($shape as $key=>$value){
    if($key=='parts'){
        [...]
```

I've tried using `array_values` and running the loops on elements by numeric key.

I've tried renaming all the variables to completely random strings.

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Instead of `var_dump($shape)`, can you `var_dump(array_keys($shape))`? I suspect 'parts' is a key, but a level deeper. Like: `$shape['foo']['parts']`.

Comment: Or `var_dump($shape['parts'])`

Comment: either you or the php complier is wrong, im betting on you

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `var_dump(array_keys($shape))` on the line immediately before the first `foreach` gives me: `array(7) { [0]=> string(4) "xmin" [1]=> string(4) "ymin" [2]=> string(4) "xmax" [3]=> string(4) "ymax" [4]=> string(8) "numparts" [5]=> string(9) "numpoints" [6]=> string(5) "parts" }`, as expected

Comment: @MathieuImbert `var_dump($shape['parts'])` on the line immediately before the first `foreach` gives me: `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["points"]=> array(175) { [0]=> array(2) { [...]`, as expected

Comment: @Tortoise, your script is going to hit line 246 multiple times since it's in a while-loop. Either check all iterations or add something like `if(!isset($shape['parts']){/*log and exit*/}`

Comment: @Dagon Yes, the majority of coding problems are caused by either the compiler or the coder... I am aware of this...

Comment: So `parts` is a key but you get a warning that's it's an illegal offset? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I've noticed. That's probably why I've spent the last 36 hours or so raging at it.

Comment: If helpful: platform is PHP 5.3.8 MSVC9 x86

Comment: In some cases `$shape['parts']` might be set, but sometimes not an array. Can you try adding a `if (!is_array($shape['parts'])) {var_dump($shape['parts']);exit;}`?

Comment: @MathieuImbert It certainly looks like an array to me, considering that its `var_dump` begins `array(1) { [0]=>`... I'll try that, but I really don't think it'll do much.

Comment: Of course, but as @FritsvanCampen stated, it is enclosed in a while loop. And if it is not a good fit for a `foreach` loop, it is obviously not an array somewhere in the process. I realize my advice sound obvious, but rationalization is the only weapon in such cases. I can see no reason why you hit a PHP warning, except for the obvious reason.

Comment: array_values (line 244) should be stripping the key names and leaving numeric keys...

Comment: @TasosBitsios Alas, that's not actually there; I accidentally merged in one of my error tests. I'll fix the code.

Comment: @MathieuImbert Oh. My. God. It was failing on the last iteration. I didn't think of that before, for some reason. THANK YOU. ALL THE TIMES. I'm an idiot.

Comment: inject in line 245: `if (!isset($shape['parts'])) die(var_dump($shape));` and tell us the output...

Comment: @Tortoise ;) When it seems impossible, assume you are wrong, and go back to basics. Take the error message literally and dig from there.